# Concat Arrays with For Loop

Tags: arrays, concatenation

After experimenting with the reduce method to flatten an array, I tried using a similar approach with a for-loop. 
Can anyone explain why the for-loop doesn't flatten the array using concat? 
P.S. I know that I can use a nested for-loop with Array.isArray to flatten as well. Just expected concat to work in a for-loop after seeing how reduce flattened the array.

```js
var arrays = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5],
  [6]
];

console.log(arrays.reduce(function(arr, elem) {
  return arr.concat(elem);
}, []));

function flatten(arr) {
  var flat = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    flat.concat(arr[i]);
  }
  return flat;
}
console.log(flatten(arrays));
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`concat` doesn't modify the array. To make your code work, you'd have to assign the value to it, then it'll do the same

```js
var arrays = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6]];

function flatten(arr) {
    var flat = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        flat = flat.concat(arr[i]);
    }
    return flat;
}
console.log(flatten(arrays));
```

Just a sidenote - with ES6, you can flatten an array even easier using the spread operator `[].concat(...arr);`

```js
var arrays = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6]];

function flatten(arr) {
    return [].concat(...arr);
}
console.log(flatten(arrays));
```

And nowadays even easier, using `flat()`

```js
const arrays = [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6]];
console.log(arrays.flat());
```